# Method to return posts and related meta data in wordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

WordPress has a method (`get_posts()`) to get all posts info, but I need a function to get posts info with it's meta data from 'wp_postmeta` table.
Is there any function in WordPress to get me an array with posts and it's meta data?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just `foreach` and [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)?

Answer (score 0):

[You can use WP_Query for custom queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

if you want get all posts with meta you can exec this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` on `wp_posts`.`ID`  = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`
```

then you can try this:

```
function posts_with_meta(){
    global $wpdb;

    $posts_with_meta = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
        on $wpdb->posts.`ID` = $wpdb->postmeta.`post_id`
        "
    );

    return $posts_with_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can merge the post metadata and post data with this code:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1, // -1 is for all
    'post_type'     => 'location', // or 'post', 'page'
    'orderby'       => 'date', // or 'date', 'rand'
    'order'         => 'ASC', // or 'DESC'

    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Usage
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $result = get_post_meta($post->ID);
    $post->postMeta = $result;
}
```